# Ansible -m shell and find command

Tags: find, pipe, ansible

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

```
ansible -m shell -i test.txt -a "sudo find / -regex '.*\(tar\|zip\)$' -type f 2>/dev/null | while read i; do echo $i; done"
```

The problem is the "while" part. It doesn't show any result. When I run it directly in Bash, then all is OK.

(I need this "while" part, because I do various operations with files found by the `find`, like `unzip` and `grep`)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$i` occurs in double-quotes, it'll be expanded (to nothing) before being passed to `ansible` as part of the command string. You need to escape it: `... do echo \$i; ...`.

BTW, you should technically do the same with the backslashes and `$` that're part of the regular expression, like `'.*\\(tar\\|zip\\)\$'`. You don't really need to, since the characters after them happen to be ones that can't be interpreted as escape sequences or `$` expansions, so the shell will leave them alone, but using syntax that "just happens to work" always makes me nervous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

In respect to the first answer, escaping `$i` to `\$i` let it run correctly.

```
ansible test --user ${ACCOUNT} --ask-pass --become --module-name shell --args "find /home/{{ ansible_user }} -regex '.*\(tar\|zip\)$' -type f 2>/dev/null | while read i; do echo \$i; done"
```

Instead of using `sudo` within the shell arguments, [`--become`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) might be a better approach.

Regarding

> When I run it directly in Bash, then all is OK.

as far as I understand the Ansible [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) module, it is doing something like `/bin/sh -c`. If a Bash is necessary you may use it in example via `--args "/bin/bash -c '...'"`.

**Thanks to**

- [What's the difference between Ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804071/)
- [Difference between `shell` and `command` in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663332/)
- [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/)

Comment: Thanks for your improvements of my Ansible command. Much appreciated.